# WPF (ClickOnce) deployment over internet

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, iis, clickonce

Morning, I have been trying to work out the root cause or possible a solution for a our `ClickOnce` deployment.

**Background:** We have a `WPF` application which can be triggered either through start up argument or without it. This application is been deployed using `ClickOnce` and published to one of our local server.
Users within intranet can download/execute successfully and all work as expected.

**What has changed:** We recently had requirement to access this application from internet. To achieve this, we have created an `asp.net` web application and pointed to one of our sub domain. This application has a webpage with a button.

The idea is to invoke locally deployed `WPF` application on button click.

```
var url = string.Format("{0}?appId={1}", "http://serverip/wpfclient/wpf.application", Session["appreference"].ToString());
            Process.Start(url);
```

**Issue:** We have tried IE/Chrome/Mozilla/Opera to access the above mentioned website. However, none of the browsers open WPF applications. On click it does nothing. Additionally, we followed [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx) guide to ensure all recommended steps.

> However, still we couldn't get this work. Is there anything else we
>   should be following to get this work?

**What we have done so far:**

1. assembly is signed in using certificate
2. application/.config extensions in IIS unchecked
3. clickOnce security setting and choose Zone as Internet with full trust.

**Debug result:**

1. We were able to debug the asp.net server code to see whether handle
   is executing and it does.
2. We were able to inspect request/response
   using `Fiddler` but couldn’t find anything abnormal in log

**Request**
POST /?var=2010703 HTTP/1.1

Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml,

Referer: http://xxxxx.xxxxxx.co.uk/?var=2010703

Accept-Language: en-GB

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Length: 526

DNT: 1

Host: xxxxx.xxxxxx.co.uk

Pragma: no-cache

Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=qp5oszednhvasjqhws4dpoyh

**Response**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Cache-Control: private

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Content-Encoding: gzip

Vary: Accept-Encoding

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 07:32:40 GMT

Content-Length: 1247

Comment: Have you tried this with a very simple Windows Forms app (i.e. just display a "Hello World" form)? Just to check that it would work if it was Windows Forms.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I haven't since it doesn't serve the purpose.

Comment: But if you tried it and it didn't work, it would indicate that your problem is nothing to do with WPF, which would be an important piece of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update, we have changed our internet group policy to exempt this link and doing so, we are able to launch our application. So the solution was to tune the group policy to accommodate the link.